# SQL can't found any values

Tags: mysql

i'm having trouble returning values of sql rows, my SQL request work well on console but can't return a row of it with my code, any help ? thanks !

```
<?php
require_once 'sql.php';
$sqlConnexion = new mysqli($hn,$un,$pw,$db);
if($sqlConnexion->connect_error){
die ('Soucis de connexion SQL');}

$date = date("d/m/y G:i:s");
if(isset($_POST['zoneDeText'])){
$area = $_POST['zoneDeText'];

  $queryone= "SELECT SortieTraitée FROM entry WHERE entréesUtilisateurs=?";
  $instruction = $sqlConnexion->prepare($queryone);
  if(!$instruction->prepare($queryone)){
      echo "$instruction->errno";

  }else{
  $instruction->bind_param('s', $area);
  $instruction->execute();
  $result = $instruction->get_result();

  while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
  foreach ($row as $out){
   if($out == $area){
      echo $out;
   }elseif($out != $area){
      echo 'Still not found';
            }
        }
    }
      $instruction->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: `SELECT entréesUtilisateurs=? FROM entry` can not show you correct results. What happened to your `where` clause?

Comment: The *nothing* tag refers specifically to the VB.Net `nothing` value. Tags here have specific meanings. Please do not just randomly add them because they have words that seem familiar. Read the tag description before using it to make sure it's appropriate. If you're still not sure, leave it off and someone here will add it for you if needed. It's also important to include a tag for the language you're using when asking a code-related question, which you've not done. Please [edit] to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually print anything, you just `return` the value, which makes no sense unless your code is inside a function.

```
if($out == $area){
    return $out;
}
```

The documentation http://php.net/return says:

> If return is called from within the main script file, then script execution ends.

Unless the code you show above has been included in another PHP script, that means it will just end the script and output nothing.

There are several other confusing things your script, but the above is probably the one directly responsible for the problem you're asking about.

---

Here's how I might write this code:

```
if (isset($_POST['zoneDeText'])) {
  $area = $_POST['zoneDeText'];

  $queryone = "SELECT SortieTraitée FROM entry WHERE entréesUtilisateurs=?";
  $instruction = $sqlConnexion->prepare($queryone);

  // if the prepare fails, it is false 
  if ($instruction === false) {
      // false is not an object, it has no error attribute
      // the error is an attribute of the connection
      die($sqlConnexion->error);
  }

  $instruction->bind_param('s', $area);
  $instruction->execute();
  $result = $instruction->get_result();

  // if there are zero rows in the result, the while loop
  // will finish before it starts, so there will be no output
  // so first check for a result of zero rows in the result
  if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
    echo("Found zero rows");
  } else {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo $row["SortieTraitée"];
    }
  }
  $instruction->close();
}
```

Comment: thanks, yes, as you can see i'm a beginner =) yes the return was a terrible mistake :( but even if i replace it with let say "echo $out" it won't show me anything any idea why ? thank =)

Comment: @user2690397, remember that it is traditional on Stack Overflow to thank people by upvoting their answer, and/or marking the most helpful answer as the 'accepted answer'. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote